# How to ensure only one Play instance actually runs a method at one certain moment

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a `Play` plugin that executes a method every 15 minutes like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.{Application, Plugin}
import akka.actor.Cancellable

class AuthPlugin(app: Application) extends Plugin {

  private var cancellableDoSomething: Option[Cancellable] = None

  ...

  override def onStart = {
    cancellableDoSomething = Some(
      Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(0.seconds) {
        doSomething.foreach { _ =>
          Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(15.minutes)(doSomething)
        }
      }
    )
  }

  override def onStop = {
    cancellableDoSomething.foreach(_.cancel)
  }
}

object AuthPlugin {

  ...

  def doSomething: Future[Unit] = {
    // Access to shared DB here...
  }
}
```

Let's suppose I've two instances of my `Play` application running on two distinct hosts, and of cource, each of them invokes `doSomething` every 15 minutes.

How do I ensure only one instance actually runs `doSomething` at one certain moment?

**EDIT**

The two `Play` instances access the same database, and `doSomething` processes the records in state `pending`. After a record in state `pending` has been processed, it is updated to state `processed`.

If the first `Play` instance queries the database for pending orders and while processing them the second `Play` instance runs the same query, it obtains a record set that consists also of pending orders already queried by the first `Play` instance but not processed yet. To avoid this, a `Play` instance should be able to invoke `doSomething` if and only if there is no other instance that is already executing it.

I could implement a kind of DB-based semaphore where the first `Play` instance that acquires it sets the value of a field to `1` or whatever else... but this solution is not stable because if that `Play` instance fails and never sets back the field to `0`, then other `Play` instances are no longer able to acquire the semaphore and invoke `doSomething`.

Comment: I assume you have a shared resource issue. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: As each  play app runs on seperate JVMs on different hosts you have 2 options: to use some external service for synchronising or to implement such synchronization by yourself for example with help of Akka

Comment: just create nfs share on database machine create a file and use man 2 flock on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a database where a locking mechanism is provided for certain operations, such as during UPDATE**
Example: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html):

> "MySQL uses row-level locking for InnoDB tables"
>
> "MySQL uses table-level locking for MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE tables"

That means you can get a locking mechanism using any of the above tables.

**Locking Procedure**

1. Get a job your machine wants to work on. Let's say you get one with  `jobId=123`.

2. Attempt atomic locking.

```
UPDATE jobs SET state='started' and worker='worker1' WHERE jobId=123 AND state='pending';
```

3. Check that lock acquired was acquired by machine `'worker1'`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM JOBS where jobId=123 AND state='started' AND worker='worker1';
```

4. If the above query returned 1, then `'worker1'` has reserved the job successfully, to the exclusion of all other machines. If the query returned 0, that means some other machine (e.g. `'worker2'`) acquired the lock first.

**When the Job is Finished**

```
UPDATE jobs SET state='finished' WHERE jobId=123;<br>
```

**What if the reserving machine fails?**

When attempting the lock (via UPDATE), also add a timestamp column. Then, have another background job periodically clear jobs that are older than, say, 1 hour but where the state is still "started."

Comment: Yes... this is more or less what I had in mind... except I use MongoDB. Tx anyway.